# Error in "Children enjoy listening to ghosts stories especially on Halloween night"?

Tags: sentence-structure, exam-questions, error

I have been preparing (in India) for a competition exam for a few months. I was solving a book but got something which didn't make any sense to me. I have written a sentence below and we need to find the error in the sentence. The error I found it shows wrong and the answer it shows it's not making sense to me. I have mentioned the answer as well after the sentence.

> Children enjoy listening to (A) ghosts stories (B) especially on Halloween night (C) No error (D)

The book says answer is "Children enjoy listening to (A)".

Comment: Does the letter designate the word or the phrase, before or after it?  "Children enjoy listening to" contains no error.  "Ghosts" is in wrong number, needs to be singular.  I would also put a comma after "stories".

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. There is a very specific concern here that can be explained in a way that applies to more than just this one sentence.

Comment: I just came across the same question and I think there is error in B.

Answer (score 5):

The plural of "ghost story" is "ghost stories". In general, English does not have plural forms of adjectives, unlike (for instance) French.

Comment: Is "ghost" technically an adjective here? I would describe it as a noun used as a modifier. (But just nit-picking, your point is a good one)

Comment: @IanF1 - It's a good nitpick, actually. But a modifier behaves like an adjective in this case.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Thanks for your help but please check my question again. I also chose the same answer but when I checked the answer it showed option A and it's "Children enjoy listening to".

Comment: As a moderately well-educated American speaker, I see nothing wrong at all with "Children enjoy listening to". Are you sure you've got the phrasing right? Or it may be an error in the book. (B) was the part in error.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I think it was a typo.

Comment: Similar to "tooth brush". People use a tooth brush, not a teeth brush, even if they have more than one tooth. And a single story about two ghosts is still a "ghost story", not a "ghosts story".